# jQuery/js stores/appends variable each time a popup is called, but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup which gets a variable (userid) when called, and that variable I give to a function when I select something within the popup.

The first variable each time is new, which is how it should be.
But the second variable appends and contains all the values from the last times the popup was called. 

But why and how can I prevent that?

JS code:

```
$(".class").click(function() {
    var userid    = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".popup").toggle();
    console.log('first');
    console.log(userid);

    $(".popup td").click(userid,function() {
        console.log('second');
        console.log(userid);

        $(".popup").hide();
    });
});
```

Console readout:

```
"first"
"1"
"second"
"1"

"first"
"2"
"second"
"1"
"2"

"first"
"3"
"second"
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

Comment: Never put an event handler inside another event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that for every click on a `.class` element, you're adding a *new* event handler for clicks on `.popup td` elements. So:

First click:

```
"first"
"1"
"second"
"1"
```

Makes sense, the click output `1` and bound `1` to the handler it added, so clicking that `.popup td` shows `1` as well.

```
"first"
"2"
"second"
"1"
"2"
```

Also makes sense: You've clicked a second time (apparently on `2`), so the `.class` handler shows `2` and binds a **new** event handler to the `.popup td` that will receive `2`. Then when you click the `.popup td` element, it fires both of the handlers assigned to it (in the order they were assigned), so you see `1` followed by `2`.

(And then the same sort of thing happens the third time, and so on, and so on...)

If your intention is to *replace* the handler, you can do that like this:

```
$(".class").click(function() {
    var userid    = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".popup").toggle();
    console.log('first');
    console.log(userid);

    $(".popup td").off("click.foo").on("click.foo", userid, function() {
        console.log('second');
        console.log(userid);

        $(".popup").hide();
    });
});
```

That removes any previous `click.foo` handler before attaching a new one.

**However**, I wouldn't go attaching and detaching handlers like that. Instead, just have the `.class` handler set a variable that the (one) `.popup td` handler can use:

```
var clickedUserId;                         // Declare it outside either handler
$(".class").click(function() {
    clickedUserId    = $(this).attr('id'); // Set it here
    $(".popup").toggle();
    console.log('first');
    console.log(clickedUserId);
});
$(".popup td").click(function() {
    console.log('second');
    console.log(clickedUserId);            // Use it here

    $(".popup").hide();
});
```

---

Just for completeness: I wouldn't make `clickedUserId` a *global*, the global namespace is already Way Too Crowded, just declare it in a scope shared by the two event handlers. If you don't already have a scope handy, wrap the above in an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE):

```
(function() {
    var clickedUserId;                         // Declare it outside either handler
    $(".class").click(function() {
        clickedUserId    = $(this).attr('id'); // Set it here
        $(".popup").toggle();
        console.log('first');
        console.log(clickedUserId);
    });
    $(".popup td").click(function() {
        console.log('second');
        console.log(clickedUserId);            // Use it here

        $(".popup").hide();
    });
})();
```